# Asp.net MVC utilising WCF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

Looking into developing new startup with potential of hopefully having high volume.

Initial idea was to straight away have MVC talk to WCF services to create our Application Servers.

However after a little contemplating just wondering what benefits would I gain from using WCF services with MVC application?

If performance became an issue we could just keep adding new front web servers instead of application servers.

Enlighten me please, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't start using fancy technology for the sake of using it or because it looks cool on paper. You'll have to support it and sometimes find yourself making things overly complicated because of the introduction of something that might not be necessary.

Said that, my current project also uses MVC 2 in combination with WCF. There it was an architectural decision made before I came to the project as they want to spread the tiers on different servers in different domains (outside and inside DMZ). The WCF service can only be called from the server hosting the MVC application so it should increase security.